# Email Password Change without login to cpanel

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services, cpanel, web-hosting

Friends, I would like a permanent solution to a script to change password without email access cpanel.

I tried the cpanel api but I could not ...

Could you help me?

I need a page where the User enter the email address and new password, after which the password is changed ...

Please help me ...

Answer (score 1):

If you have current password then you can change it through webmail otherwise you will have will have you to change it through cPanel.

Answer (score 1):

The cPanel email passwords have the same format as default linux users. There is a folder called etc/ in /home/cpaneluser/. In that folder you have a folder with the domain name (like abc.com). In the end in /home/cpaneluser/etc/abc.com/ you have a passwd file containing the email users like office/contact/etc (without the domain name) and a shadow file containing the md5 hash for the password.

Basically you can create a simple php script where the user initially enters his complete email address. Based on that you extract the domain, then you search that domain in /etc/userdomains in order to find out the cPanel user. Then you do a cd /home/cpaneluser/etc/domainname and replace the current md5hash for the actual email password with a new generated md5hash for the new password you did setup.

Of course probably there are other solutions or you can use perl or whatever.

Alternatively you could develop of script that uses passwdpop function from cPanel API (https://documentation.cpanel.net/#Email::passwdpop)